# Android CardView Remove multiple select with custom onItemSelectedListener

Tags: android, android-cardview, multiple-select

I'm having a problem regarding CardView that has multiple select. The problem is in this pic [image: Here]

I want it to just mark one cardview so that if I press another one, then the previous one will turn white (Single select). So basically I want it to have the same behavior as radio buttons.

The code for my `onBindViewHolder` in my Adapter. I believe it is here it fails to do the single select.

```
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull MyViewHolder holder, int position) {
    holder.txt_treatment_name.setText(treatmentList.get(position).getTreatmentName());
    holder.txt_treatment_price.setText(treatmentList.get(position).getTreatmentPrice());
    holder.txt_treatment_description.setText(treatmentList.get(position).getTreatmentDescription());

    if (cardViewList.contains(holder.card_treatment))
        cardViewList.add(holder.card_treatment);

    holder.setiRecyclerItemSelectedListener((view, pos) -> {
        // Set white background for all cards that aren't selected
        for (CardView cardView:cardViewList)
            cardView.setCardBackgroundColor(context.getColor(R.color.colorWhite)); //

        //Set background for selected item
        holder.card_treatment.setCardBackgroundColor(context.getColor(R.color.colorPrimaryLight));
        holder.txt_treatment_name.setTextColor(context.getColor(R.color.colorWhite));
        holder.txt_treatment_description.setTextColor(context.getColor(R.color.colorWhite));
        holder.txt_treatment_price.setTextColor(context.getColor(R.color.colorWhite));

        //Send broadcast to tell BookingActivity to enable Button NEXT
        Intent intent = new Intent(Common.KEY_ENABLE_BUTTON_NEXT);
        intent.putExtra(Common.KEY_TREATMENT, treatmentList.get(pos));
        localBroadcastManager.sendBroadcast(intent);
    });
}
```

And the code for my `ViewHolder` that has the custom itemSelectedListener

```
static class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener {
    TextView txt_treatment_name, txt_treatment_price, txt_treatment_description;
    CardView card_treatment;
    IRecyclerItemSelectedListener iRecyclerItemSelectedListener;

    void setiRecyclerItemSelectedListener(IRecyclerItemSelectedListener iRecyclerItemSelectedListener) {
        this.iRecyclerItemSelectedListener = iRecyclerItemSelectedListener;
    }

    MyViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
        super(itemView);

        txt_treatment_name = itemView.findViewById(R.id.txt_treatment);
        txt_treatment_price = itemView.findViewById(R.id.txt_price);
        txt_treatment_description = itemView.findViewById(R.id.txt_description);
        card_treatment = itemView.findViewById(R.id.card_treatment);

        itemView.setOnClickListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        iRecyclerItemSelectedListener.onItemSelectedListener(v, getAdapterPosition());
    }
}
```

I followed a youtube guide [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=G6z1uLPqRDY) and in his example, it works just fine. I just don't know how to remove the multiple select and implement "Radio button" behavior in this.

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your adapter have a global position int, that holds which position is clicked:

```
private int clickedPosition=-1;


//in onbindviewholder

if(clickedPosition==position){
//changed color

        holder.card_treatment.setCardBackgroundColor(context.getColor(R.color.colorPrimaryLight));

}else{

//white color

        holder.card_treatment.setCardBackgroundColor(context.getColor(R.color.White));


}


//when you click some item
holder.setiRecyclerItemSelectedListener((view, pos) -> {

//hold the clicked position and change color 
holder.card_treatment.setCardBackgroundColor(context.getColor(R.color.colorPrimaryLight));
clickedPosition = position;
this.notifyDataSetChanged();

});
```